# Multiple declaration error in C using DOSBox version 0.74

Tags: c, data-structures

I'm creating a simple project on DOSBox version 0.74, Double Linked List.
I created  3 files:

- A header file DLinkedList.h contains structure of list node and functions prototypes.
- DLinkedList.c file. contains the implementation of these functions.
- main.c file

The header file is included in both of the other two files.
and the `DLinkedList.c` is included also in `main.c` , usually I don't do this but DOSBox says that the functions in `DLinkedList.c` aren't defined in `main()` . those errors solved when I included the `.c` file in `main.c`.

Now my problem is that I get this error

```
ERROR DLinkedList.h  multiple declaration of listnode
```

this is the code in the header file besides the prototypes.

```
typedef struct listnode{
    int id;
    char name[SIZE];
    struct listnode *next;
    struct listnode *prev;
}ListNode;

typedef struct list{
ListNode *head;
int size;
}List;
```

Comment: Probably not your main problem, but `char name[];` is illegal; you must specify a size

Comment: also, DOSBox is a DOS emulator, not a compiler. Are you running some  compiler under DOSBox ?

Comment: The main problem here is actually quite likely some crap compiler from the dinosaur age. Just what is `char name[]` in the middle of a struct supposed to mean? Is it a pointer? Is it an array with size zero? Is it a flexible array member which is allowed to grown downwards and greedily consume its fellow struct members? Nobody knows, because it isn't standard C.

Comment: I edited the array size thing, thank you for mentioning this.

Answer (score 4):

> and the DLinkedList.c is included also in main.c.

You don't include C files in other C files.

The accepted practice is to create a *header* file containing the declarations (not definitions) and then include that.

What's probably happening is that you're including the header file *twice,* once in `main.c` and again in the `DLinkedList.c` included by `main.c`.

So, for example, if your `DLinkedList.c` file was:

```
int getFortyTwo (void) { return 42; }
```

then the equivalent `DLinkedList.h` file would have the prototype:

```
int getFortyTwo (void);
```

The only scenario I can think of where you may think you need to include the C file is if you're doing full compilation/linking of `main.c` on its own, and that's not the way to do it.

You would *compile* `main.c` and the other C file into individual object files, then *link* those two together.

Comment: I mentioned that I don't do this when I use pelles C for example but, here with DOSBox when I exclude the .c file from main.c. I get so many linker errors say for example "Linker error undefined symbol _ListFull in module main.c" ListFull is one of the functions.

Comment: @Rsaleh: yes, I understand that, and I've given you the solution to it. Use a suitable header file. Otherwise, you'll run into problems surprisingly similar to, well, the problem you've run into :-)

Answer (score 3):

What you need is  a header guard [a.k.a [include guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard)] to solve the `multiple declaration` issue.

Re-write your header file in this way

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_
#define __MY_HEADER_

//header file containts


#endif
```

Then you can include it as many number of times you want. This header guard ensures only one occurence of your header file defintions.

Also, please ensure, not to `#include` `.c` files. There are `.h` files to be used as header files and the two different types exist for a reason.

Then, your code snippet shown here has some problem. You cannot use `char name[];` unless you use an initializer. specify the dimention of array, like `char name[64];`

Lastly, regarding the missing definitions in `main.c`, you need to add the function prototypes [which servers as the `forward declatation`] of the functions defined in `DLinkedList.c` to the header file, which will be included to `main.c`. Otherwise, your `main.c` will not be able to *see* the functions.